# How do I disable the touchpad while I'm typing?

Tags: debian, touchpad, crunchbang

I'm looking to disable the touchpad in Crunchbang 11 (Waldorf) while I am typing. The processes I've found online do not work for me.

All guides I have found ([this thread](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=4765), for instance) indicate to toggle a flag in `/etc/hal/fdi/policy/`, but the entire `/etc/hal` folder does not exist on my computer. Since Crunchbang uses Openbox, I found [this guide](http://www.ehow.com/how_7473439_disable-touchpad-typing-openbox.html); however, this option does not exist within my version of Openbox.

`find | grep shmconfig.fdi` (the file typically modified in these guides) returns no lines; that file does not exist on my computer. That is to be expected, though; the guides state that the file may not exist.

How do I disable the touchpad while I'm typing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `syndaemon` should do the job. It can be found in the package
`xserver-xorg-input-synaptic`. From the [man
page](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=syndaemon&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+unstable+sid&format=html&locale=en)

> **syndaemon**  - a program that monitors keyboard activity and disables the
>     touchpad when the keyboard is being used.
>
> Disabling  the  touchpad  while typing avoids unwanted movements of the
>     pointer that could lead to giving focus to the wrong window.

Example:

```
syndaemon -i 1 -t -d
```

This deactivates tapping after one second.
There is also
[synclient](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=synclient&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+unstable+sid&format=html&locale=en)
with more options to set up the touchpad.

Comment: Does this command survive a reboot?